# Why can't output value of hadoop map be null?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I just want to use hadoop mapreduce to sort my lines of log. I put all fields of the line as the output key, and set output value as null. But when run, null pointer exception is raised at line

```
context.write(new Text(outkeystr), null);
```

So why can't output value of hadoop map be null?
Why output value of hadoop reduce can (I tested)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the explict value `null` but you can use a `NullWritable` class if you don't care about the Value

Comment: This will be exact statement "context.write(new Text(outkeystr), NullWritable.get());"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot output a null value. You can output a null key though:

```
context.write(null, new Text(outkeystr));
```